# Activex issue and ocx issue

Tags: activex, ocx

I have created Activex in Vb
It contain one public method in VB

When I call it through javascript

it says 'object does not support properties or method'

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the error message in the following conditions:
1. The method or property is not a valid one.
2. The ActiveX control is not available on the machine.

If the method/property is called in a right way, please check whether you've installed/registered the ActiveX control on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, you have not have the activex module registered in the Windows registry.

Try registering the ActiveX as shown here:

```
C:\Windows\System\regsvr32 name_of_activex.ocx
```

Replace 'name_of_activex.ocx' with the **full path to your activex module**.